Is the Moon really oscillating around its orbit as seen from Earth?
While simulating today's eclipse, I see something I have never noticed or learnt:
Stellarium shows an oscillation of the Moon's trajectory around its orbit as seen from Earth.
Is it real or a Stellarium glitch (I doubt, knowing its quality/accuracy)?
If real, what is the mechanical cause?
Thank you.


Can you give some details on how you created that plot?

I basically took Stellarium to today, and activated the Show Orbits and the Show Trails options.

It's probably a perspective effect, a result of being on a plant that's revolving   You are seeing lunar parallax

I actually just put myself on one pole and the effect vanishes so you are right. Thanks a lot.

I'll write it up as an answer then.

What you're seeing is exactly as James suggest.  However there are a lot of actual, real oscillations in the Moon's movement.  Just not as large on such a small timescale.  These are mostly caused by non-uniform gravitational forces from the Sun and Earth, and to a lesser extent, other planets.

This is a perspective effect.  We are on a revolving planet, so as the planet rotates, the moon will appear to move slightly with respect to the distant stars. You can see that if you place yourself on the North Pole, then the effect will vanish.
However there are a lot of actual, real oscillations in the Moon's movement. Just not as large on such a small timescale. These are mostly caused by non-uniform gravitational forces from the Sun and Earth (from Greg's comment)
